# Parameters not being sent to a URL in Django redirect

Tags: python, django

I want to send a get parameter to a specific URL e.g. http://127.0.0.1:8000/foo?myid=99

However this code is not creating the get parameter:

```
def BarView(request):
    return redirect(reverse('foo'), myid=99)
```

But the resulting URL is just http://127.0.0.1:8000/foo/

```
def FooView(request):
    return HttpResponse('''<html lang="en"><body><p>myid: %s</p>
        </body>''' % request.GET.get('myid', ''))
```

In "urls.py":

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('foo/', views.FooView, name='foo'),
    path('bar/', views.BarView, name='bar'),
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reverse` will render your URL name as a string. So if you want to add a get parameter, just concatenate it with a string like the following:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def BarView(request):
    query = "?myid=99"
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('foo') + query)
```

Note that I used `HttpResponseRedirect`